# mmap: Operation not permitted

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to use mmap in user space to read the physical memory where 'mem_map' starts. It's an array that contains all the physical pages. This is a i386 machine running 3.0 kernel.

The code is like this:

```
....

//define page size
//
#define PAGE_SIZE 0x1000 //4096 bytes
#define PAGE_MASK (PAGE_SIZE - 1)

....

  /* open /dev/mem file*/
  if((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1) {
        printf("/dev/mem could not be opened.\n");
    perror("open");
        exit(1);
  } else {
    printf("/dev/mem opened.\n");
  }

  /* Map one page */
  printf(" mem_map is at physical addr: 0x%x\n", mem_map_phy_addr);

  map_base = mmap(0, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, (mem_map_phy_addr & ~PAGE_MASK)); //mem_map_phy_addr is at 0x356f2000

  if(map_base == (void *) -1) {
    printf("Memory map failed. err num = %d\n",errno);
    perror("mmap"); //failed here
  } else {
    printf("Memory mapped at address %p.\n", map_base);
  }
```

I ran this as a root. The output is:

```
/dev/mem opened.
 mem_map is at physical addr: 0x356f2000
Memory map failed. err num = 1
mmap: Operation not permitted
```

To be sure, I googled the problem and added the following line to my /etc/sysctl.conf file:

```
vm.mmap_min_addr = 0
```

But this doesn't work either.

Anyone knows why mem_map operation like this is not permitted and how I can get around it?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, it is incorrect to use `x & ~PAGE_MASK`.  On 64 bit systems, this will truncate addresses to 32 bits.  You must cast to `uintptr_t` or equivalently wide type before taking the complement.

Comment: Did you run the sysctl command to set the value for mmap_min_addr or just edit the conf file? You have to do both.

Comment: yes, I did "sysctl -p" afterwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like the kernel has been compiled with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` enabled. This is a security feature to prevent user space access to (possibly sensitive) physical memory above 1MB (IIRC). You might be able to disable this with sysctl dev.mem.restricted.

Comment: Yes, my .config has CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y. How do I use "sysctl dev.mem.restricted"? I tried and the error is: /proc/sys/dev/mem/restricted: No such file or directory.

Comment: I guess you'll have to recompile the kernel with the option disabled.

Comment: Ok, I recompiled the kernel with CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM turned off. Now I have a new error: /dev/mem opened.
 mem_map is at physical addr: 0x356db000
Memory map failed. err num = 22
mmap: Invalid argument. This doesn't happen if I tried to map physical address at 0. Any suggestions? - Thanks.

Comment: @user899159, that's really a different question. I have no idea where the address you're using comes from.

Comment: On more recent kernels CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM is implied by HARDENED_USERCOPY and HAVE_HARDENED_USERCOPY_ALLOCATOR. So make sure to disable them as well.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem which occured when I was trying use flashrom on an APU2c4 Board with Arch Linux.

The sysctl option `dev.mem.restricted` wasn't available in my system and using a self compiled kernel was no option for me.

I worked around the problem by setting the `iomem` Kernelparameter to `relaxed` via Grub:

```
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux iomem=relaxed
```

Of course a reboot is nessesary for this solution.

Reference:
https://www.reddit.com/r/libreboot/comments/6wvyry/flashrom_failures_to_access/
https://www.flashrom.org/FAQ
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: didn't work :( `6.6.8-100.fc38.x86_64`