# Mmap DMA Coherent Memory to User Space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap, dma

I am trying to map DMA coherent memory, which I allocated in my kernel driver, to user space. There I use `mmap()` and in kernel driver I use `dma_alloc_coherent()` and afterwards `remap_pfn_range()` to remap the pages.

The purpose of mapping the DMA memory to User Space is to minimize the ioctl access to the kernel. The host must perform quite a high number of DMA coherent memory accesses and I want to access it directly in User Space instead of wasting time by using countless `ioctl()` operations.

`mmap()` returns **EPERM** (1) - **Operation not permitted**.

I found this post: [mmap: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213671/mmap-operation-not-permitted)

Answer:

> It sounds like the kernel has been compiled with CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM
>   enabled. This is a security feature to prevent user space access to
>   (possibly sensitive) physical memory above 1MB (IIRC). You might be
>   able to disable this with sysctl dev.mem.restricted.

That is the only useful info I've found. However, I see 2 issues:

1) I've allocated for test purposes only 4k. According to the above statement, only physical memory > 1MB should be a problem. I still can't mmap (anyway, for the final driver I would need a lot more dma memory, but recompiling the kernel can't be the solution to my problem) Which leads me to 2)

2) Furthermore, re-compiling the kernel is not an option as the driver should work without tweaking the kernel in a specific way.

Any ideas on this one? I appreciate the help.

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04.1**, Kernel: **4.10.0-40-generic**

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I made a copy-paste mistake which resulted in a ret=-1. So the .mmap function in the kernel driver which calls remap_pfn_range, returned -1 instead of 0. This resulted in a failing mmap() in user space

Comment: can you add your `mmap()` how exactly you call it? Also it will be useful to add part from kernel side where you call `dma_alloc_coherent()`

Comment: *"I've allocated for test purposes only 4k"* -- You're misreading the *"physical memory above 1MB"* restriction.  That *"1MB"* is not a size, but a *physical memory* address.  The 8088 CPU in the original IBM PC had maximum address space of 1MB (and 640KB of RAM), and that limitation may have persevered in some manner.