# Modify kernel parameters (mmap operation not permitted, EPERM)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, redpitaya

I am trying to run [this code](https://github.com/RedPitaya/RedPitaya/blob/master/Test/rp_remote_acquire/scope.c) on a server (RedPitaya) as well as a client (ubuntu virtual machine).

The program returns the following error messages when it is run on the client with root privileges:

```
root@VirtualBox:/.../rp_remote_acquire# ./rp_remote_acquire -m 1 -a 192.169.1.100 -p 5000 -k 0 -c 0 -d 64
mmap scope io failed (non-fatal), 1
mmap scope ddr a failed (non-fatal), 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am not sure if the segmentation fault is related to the first two errors because I only get a segmentation fault when the server is running...

The error seems to be coming from here:

```
if (param->mapped_io == MAP_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap scope io failed (non-fatal), %d\n", errno);
    param->mapped_io = NULL;
}
```

I am aware that a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213671/mmap-operation-not-permitted) has already been resolved on stackoverflow.

I tried

```
sysctl dev.mem.restricted
```

and I tried adding

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux iomem=relaxed
```

to the end of

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and rebooting, but the problem still persists...

I would like to allow this program to access the computers virtual memory and thereby hopefully resolve all the errors. It could well be that I didn't manage to set the kernel parameters correctly.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that I am launching the program as root. The program uses a ring buffer to speed up the comunication between a small SoC server and a desktop computer. I am trying to run the program on both ends (as root) and I have memory problems on the client end (the desktop computer).

Comment: Yes I just tried 
    `chmod 777 /dev/mem`, 
but it didn't help
    `crwxrwxrwx 1 root kmem 1, 1 Feb  8 17:18 /dev/mem`

Comment: According to `man 4 mem` if the kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y` you cannot do it. You can check it this way `cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep STRICT_DEVMEM` . I think the only option will be to recompile your kernel.

Comment: `/proc/config.gz` doesn't exist, but I found `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y` and `# CONFIG_IO_STRICT_DEVMEM is not set` in `/boot/config-4.15.0-29-generic`. Does anyone know of an iso that comes with a kernel that would meet my requirements?

Comment: It should not be complicated, just check out the source of the kernel you use copye the uncompressed file config-....gz in the kernel source tree .config file. modify the option CONFIG_STRICT to n and execute make  && make modules_install && make install.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The `mmap` errors and the `Segmentation fault` are both resolved now. I had [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1404426/how-to-customize-a-linux-kernel-modify-config-strict-devmem/1405247#1405247) about configuring the kernel, both problems are resolved now...